# How to add custom css file in Ext JS 5 via app.json?

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

In app.json, Ext JS 5 provide a way to include CSS file using object. Here my code in app.json

```
"css": [
        {
            "path": "bootstrap.css",
            "bootstrap": true
        },
        {
            "path": "app.css"
        }
    ],
```

It seems app.css does not include in HTML.

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to run

```
sencha app refresh
```

after adding new resources / changing `app.json`.

This will then enable the `microloader` to fetch the new resources.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, CSS files are never bundled in HTML boilerplate like JavaScript. CSS is always loaded separately.

Your configuration looks correct. Is `app.css` CSS being loaded at runtime?

Comment: app.css is not being loaded at runtime, but bootstrap.css loaded

Comment: Is app.css not being loaded in dev mode, or in testing/production build?

Comment: Ok I got a bit confused, thought you meant built mode. This explains why it worked after running `sencha app refresh` - this target will regenerate bootstrap.css that is used to load stylesheets.

Comment: running sencha app refresh will regenerate bootstrap.json ot bootstrap.css. app.css will be registered in bootstrap.json